# Custom SQL query, for sorting values with "-" as separators

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am trying to create an `ORDER BY` to sort my values properly.

The values contain a string and anywhere from zero to three sets of numbers separated by a `-`.

Example:

```
dog-2-13
dog-13-54-3
dog-25
cat-63-12
cat
```

I want them to be sorted firstly by the string in front and then by each of the "number sections" so that: `dog-2-14` > `dog-2-13` but `dog-1-14` < `dog-2-13`.

Expected result (with more examples to make it clearer):

```
cat
cat-63-12
dog-2-13
dog-2-14
dog-3
dog-13-53-3
dog-13-54-3
dog-13-54-4
dog-25
```

I'm a SQL novice and completely lost. Thank you!

Comment: And what is your expected result?

Comment: the main problem with sorting in this case is that you'll always have it sorted more or less like this:
dog-1-...
dog-10-...
dog-2-...
dog-20-...

So you've to add leading zero-values in the expected max. length if you want to use this system and solve it by SQL.

Comment: Added the expected result.

I was aware of the numeric sorting issue (where an integer is read as string) , but I was hoping that there is a way to, for example use the `CAST` function to "convert" everything after the first `-` to integer data type and then go form there...

Comment: By SQL I don't see a way, but you can write it like this:
dog-0001, dog-0002, ...
Else you've to parse it on the server by php or some other language, there you can do everything you want with the data, but it won't be so smart as you've always to read all the data.
The best is to separate animal and counter, then you can use integers and sort everything by SQL.

Comment: There is a way, I am nearly done formulating it... or them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try...

```
SELECT fieldName
FROM
(
    SELECT fieldName AS fieldName,
           SUBSTRING_INDEX( fieldName,
                            '-',
                            1 ) AS stringComponent,
           CONVERT( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( fieldName,
                                                CHAR_LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fieldName, '-', 1 ) ) + 2 ),
                                     '-',
                                     1 ),
                    UNSIGNED ) AS firstNumber,
           CONVERT( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( fieldName,
                                                CHAR_LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fieldName, '-', 2 ) ) + 2 ),
                                     '-',
                                     1 ),
                    UNSIGNED ) AS secondNumber,
           CONVERT( SUBSTRING( fieldName,
                               CHAR_LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fieldName, '-', 3 ) ) + 2 ),
                    UNSIGNED ) AS thirdNumber
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY stringComponent,
             firstNumber,
             secondNumber,
             thirdNumber
) tempTable;
```

The inner `SELECT` grabs the field name (which I am assuming is `fieldName`) and the three components and places each in a separate field and assigning an alias to that field.  Each subfield must be included at this point for sorting purposes.  The list is then sorted based upon those values.

Once this sorting is performed the outer `SELECT` chooses the original field from the list in a now sorted order.

The four outer instances of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` are used to grab the desired fields from their first argument.  As `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` grabs all of the string from the beginning to just before the first occurence of the delimiting character this makes finding the first field easy (Note : I am assuming that the first field shall contain no hyphens).

The first argument for the remaining occurences of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is formed by using `SUBSTRING()` to grab everything from just after the parsed part of `fieldName` and the following delimiting character.  It is told where this is by using `CHAR_LENGTH()` to count the number of characters before the most recent delimiting character then adding 1 for the most recent delimiting character and another 1 to point `SUBSTRING()` to the character after the most recent delimiting character.

`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` will return NULL where it encounters an absent numerical field.  Please note that NULL has a different sort value from zero.

The numerical fields are converted into unsigned Integers using `CONVERT()`.  Unsigned integers were chosen as the supplied data does not contain any real numbers.  If there are real values then you will need to replace `UNSIGNED` with `DECIMAL`.  I have also assumed that all of the numbers will be positive.

Further reading...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for such a great answer and explanation! I created a simple table in SQLfiddle and tried running the query, but I got the following error: `Every derived table must have its own alias`. I could not figure out the cause myself. Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bff2c/1 . Maybe you can spot if I am doing something wrong or there is something missing in the code. P.S. I think that "SORT BY" in your code should be "ORDER BY" right?

Comment: Sorry - my bad!  I have added `tempTable` to the end of my code.  This gives a name to the table of data produced by the inner `SELECT`.  When  such a table is used by another `SELECT` (such as our outer one) it must always be given a name, even when (as in this case) there is no further reference made to that table name.  And yes, it was meant to be `ORDER BY`.

Comment: That fixed it! It works great, except the `CONVERT()` doesn't appear to be working, for example it thinks that `11` < `2`. Again, maybe I am doing something wrong. Here's the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/766083/1

Comment: Have you tried running it in something other than SQL Fiddle?  The code is testing just fine in my copy of MySQL, but not in SQL Fiddle.  I have noticed that in SQL Fiddle recognised words such as `SELECT`, `FROM`, `CONVERT`, etc. have their colour changed from black to something else.  This change is not occurring with `SUBSTRING`, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` or `CHAR_LENGTH`, leading me to wonder how well SQL Fiddle supports the string functions.  I shall look into this further.

Comment: SQL Fiddle does support those functions.  Unfortunately, when I converted my code from my test environment I neglected to change my delimiting character from a space (I had tested on a title field of mine) to a hyphen.  I shall now correct this error in my answer.  I apologise for the oversight.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you so much for your help. You really are too nice, just like your username suggests. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  And I realised when I woke up this morning that the third number's outer `SUBSTRING_INDEX` was not called for as there is no hyphen to check for after the third one.  I have revised and tested my code and it still works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(cat,'-',2), '-', -1);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('dog-13-54-4','-',2);
+--------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('dog-13-54-4','-',2) |
+--------------------------------------+
| dog-13                               |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'dog-13-54-4','-',2), '-', -1);
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'dog-13-54-4','-',2), '-', -1) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 13                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```